# Mcrypt extension is missing in 14.04 server for mysql

Tags: 14.04, mysql, php, phpmyadmin, dmcrypt

The php mcrypt extension on ubuntu 14.04 shows that it is installed properly, but phpmyadmin says:

```
 The mcrypt extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

My current php config is [here](http://pastebin.com/QqFLdtVv). If you need anymore information, please contact me through the comments.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    php5-mcrypt is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The accepted answer is not best practice.  The [simplest, and correct answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/477608/139249](http://askubuntu.com/a/477608/139249) also has the most votes.

Comment: For others' reference, the "simplest" answer did not work for me.  `php5enmod mcrypt` froze up Apache.  `php5dismod mcrypt` freed it up again.  I went with the accepted answer and modified the path for `extension=..` and this time `php5enmod mcrypt` worked.  So yes, it's comprehensive and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo updatedb 
locate mcrypt.ini
```

Should show it located at /etc/php5/mods-available

```
locate mcrypt.so
```

Edit mcrypt.ini and change extension to match the path to mcrypt.so, example:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so
```

Now this:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt - (optional since its already enabled during phpmyadmin setup)
```

Verify that new files exists here (they should be auto created from the issue above)

```
ls -al /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ls -al /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Otherwise do the following

Create symbol links now

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Restart php5 or php5-fpm

```
sudo service php5 restart
```

Comment: This is wrong! I think you meant something like:

`sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`

And not the other way around.

Comment: Doing just `php5enmod mcrypt` worked smoothly for me.

Comment: Running `php5enmod mcrypt` will create those symbolic links for you. No need to do that manually (i.e. you can skip the `ln -s` commands).

Comment: running `php5enmod mcrypt` is the correct Ubuntu/Debian way. This answer though will work, is cumbersome and not a best practice.

Comment: many steps of above are not necessary. See @MURATSPLAT's answer.

Comment: The problem with what I expirenced, even though in 14.10, this issue was fixed, and we are now on, what is it now? 15.10. BUT, back when this was an issue, this was what was required in my case because the links were broken. My guess was that since I encountered this issue shortly after this relese, I am guessing the packages did not account for the newer structure in the slight tweek of directory structure implemented during that time period.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` does not symlink the mcrypt.ini file and hence it is required to manually run `php5enmod mcrypt` and then restarting your server for changes to take effect.

Comment: why so genius !

Comment: Thank you lord of programmers that there are so smart people out there! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 155):

Try just doing this:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

And then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I have installed fresh Ubuntu 14.04 (desktop version) to my computer. This way works for enabling mcrypt that was already installed.

Comment: Note, if you're running __nginx__ with php5-fpm -- then `php5-fpm service restart` (or reload if it's finally patched)

Comment: What those two command do is this: the 1st line is enabling module named 'mcrypt', and then restart apache2 to update the config. You can see the enabled module from `/etc/apache2/mods-available`. Enjoy LAMP life :)

Comment: `sudo service apache2 reload` is enough, no actual restart is needed (on 14.04 anyway, that's what I tried it on)

Answer (score 55):

Install `mcrypt` extension for PHP, Enable it, and Restart Apache. Following are the commands to do:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Simple. Perfect. Works without issues, at least for me on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (trusty)

Comment: It's working on ubuntu 14.10 too

Comment: I would recommend you don't include `mcrypt` in your first line. It is implicitly installed as a dependency of `php5-mcrypt`, but if you explicitly install it apt-get won't know to remove it if you later choose to un-install the `ph5-mcrypt` package.

Comment: @beldaz there is at least one server where php5-mcrypt was installed as per apt-get but mcrypt was missing because of which pnp module was not getting enabled leading to joomla installation issue. so including mcrypt makes sense for me.

Answer (score 6):

The **php5-mcrypt** Ubuntu package install the config file `mcrypt.ini` into `/etc/php5/conf.d/` which is the old PHP config directory layout.

The current way of working to enable modules in PHP5 is to put the ini files in the `/etc/php5/mods-available` directory.
Then, to enable the module in PHP5, you have to create a symbolic link to the related ini files from `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` directory to enable the module when PHP is used under Apache or / and from `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` if you want to have this module enabled when you use PHP outside Apache, in scripts run at the command line or from crontab.

Also note that in the `conf.d` directory, you can create the link to the ini file by putting a number in front of it to have the modules loaded in a specific order. Usefull when you need to load a module depending on another one.

Of course, don't forget to restart Apache if you have enabled the module for Apache :

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

My 14.04 server install only needed (after php5-mcrypt installed)

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Problem still occurs,

enable the module by adding: `extension=mcrypt.so` to

> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

and

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: For me adding the 'extension=mcrypt.so' worked after installing the mcrypt.  Lubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar

Comment: This works and is WAY simpler then the accepted answer... which will also break when it updates.

Comment: I followed every instruction here and in other places but in vain.  ubuntu 14.04.3 -- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 -- nginx/1.8.1 -- Server version: 5.7.10 - MySQL -- Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.47 -- phpMyAdmin Version: 4.0.10deb1....anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, to enable the mcrypt module, with php 5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

or with php 7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

and then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 7

```
sudo apt-get install php-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: $ sudo phpenmod mcrypt
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

Comment: $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/apache2: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the mcrypt extension for PHP by running:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: well, it says that it (command line) is installed properly, but it is somehow missing from the server as mentioned above

Comment: @jkt123: I've noticed that when you install some php module like php5-mcrypt in Ubuntu, all the files are there afterward but the module is not enabled in the main PHP config. You have to activate it manually like described in the accepted answer.

Comment: it does not work without adding the extension=mcrypt.so to php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Ubuntu 14.04 the php5-mcrypt is in the universe repository that could be disabled. In this case to install it you must enable the repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the mcrypt module:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to add php 5.5 mcrypt extension on Ubuntu 14.04 Server

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kevsin's answer worked for me, but I had to run `mkdir -p /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` and manually run the `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini` to get to work. `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` worked fine for the first symlink.

Note: I'm running PHP5-FPM. That may have been the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this, for Ubuntu 16.04 (using PHP7), here is what I did to enable mcrypt:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```