# Ubuntu Server 14.04 web server not gathering data from mysql server

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql, webserver

First of all: I am a beginner, and have only basic knowledge about linux and servers. Also, this question is kind of vague, but i hope you can help. I would be very thankful for all kinds of feedback and guidance!

I'm running Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS on a very old PC. I want to be able to host a webpage. I am hosting the same page locally using my 2010 mac mini with MAMP, and that works very well.
I needed to update my mysql login details when i transferred the project to the PC, and  also imported the database. The problem is that when i try to view the page, it gets stuck at the point where it needs to access the db to find out wether or not the client is logged on. I've tried `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql reload`, `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` and more, but it never seems to make much of a difference...

Comment: execute `sudo service mysql status` this would tell you if the server is running, if so, than you should go to the programming language you are using, is it accessing the server, did you keep the same DB name, table name, passwords the same or changed something

Comment: Post the error message you get ,, from logs or otherwise.

Comment: @younes `sudo service mysql status` returns `mysql start/running, process 1532` and yes, i have made im using the correct username and password, and the database is imported from my mac.
@bodhi.zazen at first I couldn't see any errors, but now I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 109` which might explain why nothing loads, since there is a password check on nearly every page... :/

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
I actually got it to work, and i found out that it mcrypt was causing all the problems, not mysql as i first thought. This is how i managed to solve it: [Mcrypt extension is missing in 14.04 server for mysql](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql)
Thanks for helping me out! :)