# 14.04 php5-mcrypt openCart

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I have a problem with php5 extension mcrypt.

The command

```
php5 -m | grep mcrypt
```

Outputs:

```
mcrypt
```

But during openCart install I see extension mCrypt not installed.

I've restarted apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And also tried:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: 
I will try to describe from start:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-mcrypt && sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Than, I've added links and edited mcrypt.ini, from this topic:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql
```

I've executed:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

And currently i see output for:

```
php5 -m | grep mcrypt
```

Is:

```
mcrypt
```

As far as I understand - its installed. But I still dont see it during installation of opencart.

I'm not php guru, but my phpinfo() function shows mcrypt module is in 'modules authors' section - is this a proof its installed?

Are there any steps to check, if its working.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql

Comment: Unfortunatelly not

Comment: What did you try and  what errors did you get? Kindly edit your question and add this info.

Comment: Updated main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug at the moment with php5-mcrypt module placing 'mcrypt.ini' in the wrong folder. Workaround is making symbolic links.

So, one of my first attempts to do that - was incorrect. And I didn't notice, that others didn't pass.

As far as I've figured that - I've removed symlinks with commands:

```
sudo unlink /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sudo unlink  /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

And than, added correct variant:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Restarted apache and openCart install passing now.