# PHP Failed to Load Interbase Extension

Tags: php

I have install `php5-interbase` but when I see into my `phpinfo();`, there is no inter base extension.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you restart the server after install ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for @strom that trying to help me about the issue.

Finally i got the answer. Here it is :

Try this:

```
sudo updatedb 
locate interbase.ini
```

Should show it located at /etc/php5/mods-available

```
locate interbase.so
```

Edit interbase.ini and change extension to match the path to mcrypt.so, example:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/interbase.so
```

Now this:

Verify that new files exists here (they should be auto created from the issue above)

```
ls -al /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-interbase.ini
ls -al /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-interbase.ini
```

Otherwise do the following

Create symbol links now

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/interbase.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-interbase.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/interbase.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-interbase.ini
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

i found this solution in : [Mcrypt extension is missing in 14.04 server for mysql](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql)